# Why are there two different OpenWRT firmwares for the LinkSys WRT54G3GV2-VF?

Tags: openwrt

The stable version of OpenWRT (10.03.1) does not work on the LinkSys WRT54G3GV2-VF.
The WiFi doesn't work, there are various bugs on trac that say it's fixed in trunk.

However if you browse the download locations, there are two different files for this router with no explanation as to why:

For the unreleased stable version 12.09:

(http://downloads.openwrt.org/attitude_adjustment/12.09-rc1/brcm47xx/generic/)

```
openwrt-wrt54g3gv2-vf-squashfs.bin
openwrt-wrt54g3gv2-vf-squashfs.noheader.bin
```

And in the bleeding edge folder:

(http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/brcm47xx/)

```
openwrt-wrt54g3gv2-vf-squashfs.bin
openwrt-wrt54g3gv2-vf-squashfs.noheader.bin
```

I want to upgrade to the latest version to see if the wifi is indeed fixed but can't risk bricking the device.

I suppose noheader could be the old equivalent to sysupgrade. But there is no documentation!

Does anybody know what there are two files and what they are for?

Answer (score 0):

one may be for Europa

-note, i've found a few, with (at least) different headers in the .bin file for AT, VN, and ST.

addendum: there are some which have intel chipsets and others that don't. Perhaps there are (chinaiese) knock-offs?